# Using Gnuwin32 with Visual Studio (VC++)

Tags: visual-c++, linker, gnuwin32

Can someone explain me or direct me to some usefull links which tell how to make Visual Studio 2008 use Gnuwin libraries. And please tell me which Gnuwin package I should download.(Windows xp) I have been tring hours with out any luck.

This is related to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132680/linking-link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-libgsl-a).

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for this and posted it my earlier question. In this case I am using GnuWin32/gsl library. It should be same for other GnuWin32 libs too. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132680/linking-link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-libgsl-a) to see what I found.

Thank you every one for trying to help me